# Regexp to get the utm values

Tags: regex, postgresql, amazon-redshift, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking to extract some of the utm values from a URL using regexp. My URL would look something like the below -

```
utm_source=ko_1d5b57661294a3154&utm_medium=internetq&utm_campaign=-android5436af9f1aef91a654a7255038&utm_term=searchthis&utm_content=mainpage&
```

Is there any way to have a regexp that would extract all the utm values such as utm_source, utm_medium, utm_capaign, utm_term, utm_content ?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you with your question? It helps others who use SO to indicate which answers helped/solved your question.

Answer (score 2):

You could grab all patching pairs and then convert it to an object.

***NOTE***: The object conversion is simplistic (doesn't account for multiple params of the same key, etc.).

```js
var regexp = /(?!&)utm_[^=]*=[^&]*(?=&)/g;

var query = 'utm_source=ko_1d5b57661294a3154&utm_medium=internetq&utm_campaign=-android5436af9f1aef91a654a7255038&utm_term=searchthis&utm_content=mainpage&';

var matches = query.match(regexp);
var values = matches.reduce(function(obj, param) {
  var keyVal = param.split('=');
  obj[keyVal[0]] = keyVal[1];
  return obj;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify({
  matches: matches,
  values: values
}, null, 2) + '<pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a positive lookbehind for this case. The pattern would look like that:

```
(?<=utm_[a-z]+=)\w+
```

This pattern matches any alphanumerical characters that are preceeded by "utm_???="

Answer (score 0):

Here i am what i am doing is getting every value between = and & sign.

```
/[^=]\w+(?=&)/g
```

Another one according to utm_

```
/[^utm_=]\w+(?=&)/g
```